# How much traffic does a Ubuntu server cause for updates?

Tags: ubuntu, bandwidth, traffic, update, bandwidth-measuring

Does anybody have some numbers on how much traffic/month a ubuntu server causes if automatic updates are enabled (just for fetching the apt sources and the packages)?

I have a small box which is connected to the Internet on a limited data plan (1GB/month) and I want to have it up to date, but I need to know how much bandwith I can actually use apart from traffic caused by the VPN connection and my applications.

Comment: What kind of provider gives you 1GB/month?!

Comment: @NathanC A really stingy 3G mobile data plan?

Comment: @MichaelHampton If so, a server has no business using it. :P

Answer (score 4):

It would depend entirely on the amount of packages you had installed, the amount of updates released during that month, and now often you updated apt cache.

In other words, how long is a piece of string?

Comment: I said, if automatic updates are enabled, so apt-cache will be updated once a day I think. Of course the actual amount will vary, but somebody has to have some rough numbers.

Comment: It depends on the packages you have installed, like @suprjami said.    For example, if you have apache installed, it pulls apache patches.  If you have mysql installed, it pulls mysql patches.  If you have neither installed, it doesn't ask about patches for either.  Etc.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to know would be to run your server for one month and then monitor your bandwidth usage.

Alternatively, you could use a VPS?